# Send Custom response from ProvideFault() method in WCF

Tags: wcf

I am using IErrorHandler to catch the exceptions for handling and logging purpose in my WCF service. I catch exception in ProvideFault(.....) method and from here I send Fault Exception to the client.

Below is the sample code for it..

```
public void ProvideFault(Exception error, MessageVersion version, ref Message fault)
    {
        FaultException<MyResponse> fe = new FaultException<MyResponse>(
                                new ErrorResponse
                                {
                                    MessageCode = "ERR001",
                                    MessageDetail = "Error Occured at server Side"
                                });

        MessageFault faultMsg = fe.CreateMessageFault();
        fault = Message.CreateMessage(version, faultMsg, fe.Action);
    }
```

Where MyResponse is the custom type.

Now due to some requirement change, I donot want to send FaultMessage from service. Can I send the MyResponse object from ProvideFault method? Something like as..

```
MyResponse response = new MyResponse();
response.MessageCode = "ERR001";
response.MessageDetail = "Error Occured at server Side";
Message.CreateMessage(version, response, response.Action);
```

So this can be handled at the client for all scenarios. The reason for this change is that all the client may not handling FaultException.

I do not want to use try catch in my service and send response from catch, instead I want to use IErrorHandler for this.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider the `CreateMessage(MessageVersion, string, Object)` [overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms195446(v=vs.110).aspx)? That might work for you.

Comment: I am too late to reply this... anyways sorry for that. Regarding the question I think only FaultMessage can be returned from ProvideFault(....) method. we cannot return normal response instead of this. The FaultMessage may contains custom response as FaultDetails.. Thanks.